# How to overwrite a private symbol value temporarily?

Tags: packages

I have a package file mypackage.m with

```
BeginPackage["Foo`Bar`"]
Begin["`Private`"]
tmp=2;
foo=2*tmp;
myprogram[foo]
...
End[]
EndPackage[]
```

The file is VCS controlled.  For some reason, I need to Get mypackage.m with the effect of tmp being 3 instead of 2, but I'd like to avoid explicitly changing tmp=2 to tmp=3 in the working copy of mypackage.m and having the VCS flagging it as locally modified.   Any way I can modify the way of loading the file

```
Get["mypackage.m"]
```

so I can get the effect of tmp=3 in loading it?

Comment: @Yi Wang, your suggestion is incorrect if you mean `Block[{tmp = 3}, Get["mypackage.m"]]`.  Also your comment is too undetailed to be understandable or helpful.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question...

Comment: What's the context of `tmp`? Suppose it's `Global\``, then how about `tmp = 3; SetAttributes[tmp, Protected]; Get["mypackage.m"]`? And `tmp` in a different context can be modified in a similar way.

Comment: @xzczd  I amended original post to clarify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first `Protect` the `tmp` (of course with its `Context` added) and then call the package i.e.:

```
Foo`Bar`Private`tmp = 3;
Protect[Foo`Bar`Private`tmp]
(* Or you can use: *)
(* SetAttributes[Foo`Bar`Private`tmp, Protected] *)
<< "mypackage.m"
```

A warning will come out but it doesn't matter.

Comment: Only thing I added is after Get[], I do SetAttributes[Foo`Bar`Private`tmp, Unprotected]

Comment: @qazwsx I think there's no attribute named `Unprotected`, to clear the attribute `Protected` you can use `Unprotect[Foo\`Bar\`Private\`tmp]` or `ClearAttributes[Foo\`Bar\`Private\`tmp, Protected]` :)

Comment: Yes. `ClearAttributes[Foo`Bar`Private`tmp, Protected]`. Also `Quiet[Get["mypackage`"], Set::wrsym]`.

Comment: @qazwsx You can type " \\` " instead of " ` " to make it display correctly inside the code block :)

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware.